# angular 4 using webpack how to set up app for multiple test environments

Tags: angular, webpack, development-environment

I have created Angular 4 app using Webpack .I have to set up application for 4 different regions (3 test regions and 1 production).For each different environment, service end point URLs are different.Buid and deployment process should be automated.
Please note I am not using Angular CLI.

Comment: Too bad, because the CLI has native support for environments. Maybe you can use it as an inspiration. Or just use it.

Comment: yes,CLI supports for environment but this project has already been set up using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

### Carefully follow these steps and you are good to go :)

1. Create 4 files in environment folder: (2 might there by default)
   example: 
   environment.ts, environment.prod.ts,environment.test1.ts,environment.test2.ts
2. Use this common code for every file with slight change:

   export const environment = {
     production: true, //production is true for environment.prod.ts file
                       //for other test production is false
     apiUrl: ''        //base_url of each environment
   };
3. Maintain a constant file where you will write all base urls.
   code sample of constant.ts:

   import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
   let url = environment.apiUrl;
   export const AppConstant = Object.freeze({
       BASE_API_URL: url,
   }
4. import this constant in your service or component class wherever your calling back-end.
5. In angular-cli.json:

   "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
         "environments": {
           "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
           "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
           "test1": "environments/environment.test1.ts",
           "test2": "environments/environment.test2.ts"
         }

6.

```
ng build --env=prod
ng build --env=dev / ng build
 ng build --env=test1
 ng build --env=test2
```

Hope it solves your problem. It works for me.